# Limit of an area

Tags: calculus, geometry, limits, area

I have to find the area coloured in grey when $\beta\to (\pi/2)^-$.

[image]

I'm not sure how to proceed. I though that if $\beta\to (\pi/2)^-$, then the other angle goes to zero, so the grey area goes to zero. For example if $\beta=89^{\circ}$ then the triangle looks like this
 [image]

but I don't know if this is a rigorous way to prove that the grey area is zero. any help is appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that $\tan \beta=H/10 \implies H=10 \tan \beta$.

From this we can deduce that the area of the whole triangle is 
$50 \tan \beta  $, by using the usual area triangle.

What is the area of the arc in terms of $\beta$?* Let's call it $A_{\beta}$. Then $A_{grey}=50\tan \beta-A_{\beta}$.

Now, all you have to do is evaluate
$$\lim_{\beta \to \pi/2} 50 \tan \beta-A_{\beta}.$$

*: as a hint, it is some fraction of a circle of radius $10$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got $A_{\beta}=\frac{5\pi}{18}\beta$. Is it correct? also isn't the $A_{grey}=50\tan(\beta)-A_{\beta}$? why $10\tan(\beta)$? thank you

Comment: @Victor_Krull No. $\frac{\beta}{2 \pi} \cdot A_{circle}$ should give it, no?

Comment: ah right the $\beta$ is in radians. So in the end is $A_{grey}=50\tan(\beta)-50\beta$ and then the limit is $\lim_{\beta \to \pi/2} 50 (\tan(\beta)-\beta)=\infty$ right?

Answer (score 0):

To show this rigorously, you should start by deriving an equation for the area. Notice that the shaded area is the difference between the area of the triangle and the area of the sector with radius 10 and angle $\beta$.

$$A=\frac{1}{2}\cdot10\cdot10\tan\beta-\frac{1}{2}10^2\beta=50(\tan\beta-\beta)$$

What happens now if we take $\lim_{\beta\to\pi/2^-}A$? It's not zero as you suspected.

Comment: Why $\sin(\beta)$ isn't it $\tan(\beta)$? thank you

Comment: This is incorrect for the reason that Victor mentions

Comment: Correct, I've edited it. Thanks!